# PHP fetch_array() function

Tags: php

I can't get the result for the fetch_array function. Any idea what is happening?

```
    $db = new mysqli(DB_HOSTNAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
$aa = htmlspecialchars($_POST['aa'], ENT_QUOTES);
            $sqlc = "SELECT * FROM oc_user WHERE username='".$aa."'";
            $resultc = $db->query($sqlc);

            if ($resultc === TRUE) {
            // manager email
            $mngemail = "";

                       while ($row = $resultc->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {    
                            $mngemail .= $row['email'];
                       }
        echo 'email:'.$mngemail;
```

Comment: Can you be more specific on what isn't working?  Error message perhaps?

Comment: I can't output the $mngemail variable.

Comment: That isn't necessarily where your problem is originating though.  Can you `var_dump()` the contents of `$resultc` or `$row` in your loop?  Does the output match your intended results?  Is PHP outputting any error messages?  The answers to these questions will be useful to help debug your situation.

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign the returned value from fetch_array to $row

ie:

```
while ($row = $resultc->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {       
    $mngemail .= $row['email'];
}
```

Comment: Not sure what db wrapper you are using, but check if you have a num_rows() function of some sort, ensure you are actually getting data back.  If you are, then put some output in the while loop like `var_dump($row)`.  Ensure you are getting back the data you expect

Comment: yes, I'm getting data. Now I'm getting 'array' for $mngemail variable